# button that turns off all features

Tags: c++, embedded, mbed

I am new to coding and embedded systems and I wanted to make a button that turns off and on a LED and at the same time turn off all other futures in the system.

So far I had the button turn off and on but I cant seem to get it to also update the Potentiometer. For some reason the code would check if the button is pressed and if so then the LED would turn on and then check if the LED is on and if so then turn on the other LEDs but when I change the value of the Potentiometer( which should switch to other LEDs) it would not update and stay on the same LED. So my question is how can I put another if statement that would keep updating in the while loop?

the code that I wanted to keep updating while the first LED is on is the "else if code"
Hope that made sense.
:)

note:
I don't know if my approach is right as I am looking at the LED and not the button it self, as my code checks if the LED is on rather then if the button is pressed.

(btw its not a switch which would have made my life a lot easier :( )

```
#include "mbed.h"

DigitalIn userButton (PC_10);
DigitalOut led (PC_0);

bool buttonDown = false;
BusOut leds_bus (PC_1, PB_0, PA_4);

AnalogIn pot1 (PA_5);
void init_leds ();

int cntl_val = 0;

int main ()
{
    cntl_val = pot1.read_u16 () / 32768;
    while (true)
    {
        // run forever
        if (userButton.read () == true)
        {
            // button is pressed
            if (!buttonDown)
            {           
                // a new button press
                led = !led; // toogle LED
                buttonDown = true;  // record that the button is now down so we don't count one press lots of times
                ThisThread::sleep_for (100);
            }
            else if (led.read () == true)
            {
                if (cntl_val < 1 / 3)
                {
                  leds_bus.write (4);
                }
                
                if (cntl_val > (1 / 3) && cntl_val < (2 / 3))
                {
                  leds_bus.write (2);
                }
                
                if (cntl_val > (2 / 3))
                {
                  leds_bus.write (1);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {           
            // button isn't pressed
            buttonDown = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By stating that your question is "_how can I put another if statement that..._", you have unnecessarily turned the question into an XY problem. Avoid asking how to implement _your_ solution, rather than asking how to solve your actual problem. Your description of requirements is rather unclear. You should separately describe the desired/expected behaviour, and the actual behaviour.

Comment: A button _is_ a switch.  I guess you mean it is momentary action rather then a toggle switch?  Latching a momentary action switch to give on/off operation is easy enough; your debounce solution is rather inelegant.

Comment: You also need to read the pot in the loop.

Comment: You cannot reliably debounce buttons through busy-wait sleeps. If some glitch would trigger the button read, then you block the user from pressing the button for 100ms and then won't register actual button presses during that time. This will appear to the user as if the button is unreliable mechanically, even though the problem is actually caused by software.

Comment: Anyway, the main issue here is that you haven't taken basic C classes. You cannot get floating point out of integer division. All lines such as `1 / 3` will get evaluated to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your math.  `int cntl_val` is an integer so comparing it with the fractions 1/3 and 2/3 is not going to do what you expect.  And `cntl_val = pot1.read_u16()/32768;` can set `cntl_val` to only 0 or 1.  If the max value returned by `pot.read_u16()` is less than 32768 then `cntl_val` will only be 0.

You could maybe change `cntl_val` to a float but that's probably not the best option.

Instead, try setting `cntl_val = pot1.read_u16();` (don't divide by 32768).  And then compare `cntl_val` with (32768/3) and (32768*2/3).  That's still ugly but better.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your description, but I am assuming that you have:

- An on/off indicator LED
- A three-LED level indicator
- A momentary action button for on/off control
- A potentiometer to control the input level.

And that when the system is in the "on" state you wish to indicate the potentiometer level on the level indicator?  That being the case, I suggest:

- Deal with button input/debounce separately from LED state determination.
- Simplify the level setting; you have a level 0, 1 or 2 which you can calculate by `unsigned level = (InputLevel * 3) / 32768 ;`.  You can then use that level value in a bit-shift `(1 << level)` to determine the LED to be set. Note that you had the low level set the high bit in your LED level indicator - that would require `(4 >> level)`, which is somewhat clumsy if you were to ever increase the number of LEDs.  It is easier to reverse the order of the GPIO in the `BusOut` object.

Additional advice:

- Apply the rule of "*minimal scope*", localising variables to the minimum necessary scope (you have a number of unnecessary globals.
- In "big-loop" scheduling, avoid thread delays during which useful work might otherwise be done. Your debounce delay unnecessarily determines the rate at which other work can be done in the loop. The advice would be different if you were polling the button and setting the LEDs in separate threads.

For example (not this is coded blind/untested - treat it as illustrative of the general principles - it may need debugging):

```cpp
#include "mbed.h"

int main ()
{
    static const unsigned DEBOUNCE_MS = 20u ;
    static const unsigned NUMBER_OF_LEVELS = 3u ;

    DigitalIn OnOffButton( PC_10 ) ;
    DigitalOut OnOffLed( PC_0 ) ;
    BusOut LevelIndicator( PA_4, PB_0, PC_1 ) ;
    AnalogIn InputLevel( PA_5 ) ;
    
    bool isOn = false ;
    int previous_button_state = OnOffButton ;
    std::uint64_t button_change_time = 0 ;

    for(;;)
    {
        // If debounce time expired check for button state change
        if( Kernel::get_ms_count() - button_change_time > DEBOUNCE_MS )
        {
            int current_button_state = OnOffButton ;
            
            // If button state changed
            if( current_button_state != previous_button_state )
            {
                // If button-down
                if( current_button_state != 0 )
                {
                    // Toggle isOn
                    isOn = !isOn ;
                }
                
                // Change of state and debounce update
                previous_button_state = current_button_state ;
                button_change_time = Kernel::get_ms_count() ;
            }
        }
        
        // Set the LEDs depending on On/Off state and input level        
        if( isOn )
        {
            OnOffLed = 1 ;
            
            // Set level indicator
            LevelIndicator = 1 << (InputLevel.read_u16() * NUMBER_OF_LEVELS / 32768u)  ;
        }
        else
        {
            // System inactive (Off)
            LevelIndicator = 0 ;
            OnOffLed = 0 ;
        }
    }
}
```

You might also consider separating out the button and indicator processing into separate functions to increase cohesion, minimise coupling, simplify testing and improve maintainability and comprehensibility.

```cpp
#include "mbed.h"

void updateIndicators( bool isOn ) ;
bool getOnOffState() ;

int main ()
{  
    for(;;)
    {
        updateIndicators( getOnOffState() ) ;
    }
}

bool getOnOffState()
{
    static const unsigned DEBOUNCE_MS = 20u ;

    static DigitalIn OnOffButton( PC_10 ) ;
    static bool state = false ;
    static int previous_button_state = OnOffButton ;
    static std::uint64_t button_change_time = 0 ;

    // If debounce time expired check for button state change
    if( Kernel::get_ms_count() - button_change_time > DEBOUNCE_MS )
    {
        int current_button_state = OnOffButton ;
        
        // If button state changed
        if( current_button_state != previous_button_state )
        {
            // If button-down
            if( current_button_state != 0 )
            {
                // Toggle isOn
                state = !state ;
            }
            
            // Change of state and debounce update
            previous_button_state = current_button_state ;
            button_change_time = Kernel::get_ms_count() ;
        }
    }
        
    return state ;
}

void updateIndicators( bool isOn )
{
    static const unsigned NUMBER_OF_LEVELS = 3u ;

    static DigitalOut OnOffLed( PC_0 ) ;
    static BusOut LevelIndicator( PA_4, PB_0, PC_1 ) ;
    static AnalogIn InputLevel( PA_5 ) ;

    // Set the LEDs depending on On/Off state and input level        
    if( isOn )
    {
        OnOffLed = 1 ;
        
        // Set level indicator
        LevelIndicator = 1 << (InputLevel.read_u16() * NUMBER_OF_LEVELS / 32768u)  ;
    }
    else
    {
        // System inactive (Off)
        LevelIndicator = 0 ;
        OnOffLed = 0 ;
    }
}
```